# npm install not working in windows 7 without giving any error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to node and have installed latest version of nodejs on windows 7 from windows installer for node.
**For me node install is not working without giving any error.**
After giving command

```
npm install -g express
```

**Cursors just waits and waits without showing any error message**
node(v 0.12.2) and npm(v2.7.4)
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?  Could be trying to make a connection and can't, and are not waiting long enough before you get a timeout error.

Comment: Connected to net through Wireless broadband. Also, running npm creates the .cache.json file in npm-cache folder.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem once,
in case you installed some node packages before and there is already an node_modules folder try to delete it manually and rerun the npm install command.

alternatively try to create a package.json file like this:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "module-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "Your Name",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.2.x"
  },
  "license": ""
}
```

and run `npm install` in that folder

EDIT: 
just mentioned you try to install express globally, this is not needed, [express is installed](http://expressjs.com/starter/installing.html) via `npm install express --save` (--save creates a dependency in the package.json file).

```
npm install express --save
```

**express-generator**

Another option would be to install the [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) ,this one is installed globally ;)

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

and generate your initial project this way

Comment: Thanks,but it is not working. I deleted the folder node_module from AppData\Roaming\npm. Tried with --save. No result.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

check the proxy settings.
npm config get proxy

If proxy is correct then you might had cancelled the installation in the middle.

If you had done so, delete the folder named "node_modules"  **in your current directory**  (installation folder)which will be created while installation.

and restart the install (type npm install )